# Quote attribution and confusing sources

Tags: quotes

Someone informed me of a Sandra Day O'Connor quote : "We don't accomplish anything in this world alone... and whatever happens is the result of the whole tapestry of one's life and all the weavings of individual threads form one to another that creates something."

The usage of 'form' doesn't sound right to me - maybe if there wasn't an 'of' it might make sense, but it seems like a typo. If I search for the quote, I see both this version and a version with "From" - but nowhere am I able to locate an original source or citation of what Justice O'Connor actually said. Maybe other people autocorrected it in the way I'm thinking - maybe it was originally said in this other way - maybe it was taken down and circulated incorrectly. How can I tell?

Comment: I've spent a good amount of time googling this now. It's unquestionably *from* (this quote is very popular, and every credible source I found had it quoted as *from*). Unfortunately, no one gives a more specific citation than "Sandra Day O'Connor", and I think the quote, raw, is just being passed from one hand to the next.  Nothing in Google Books or Google nGrams. But if it puts your mind at ease, even without an original source, it's definitely *from*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was transcribed incorrectly and doesn't make sense with 'form'. The biography *[Sandra Day O'Connor: U.S. Supreme Court Justice](https://books.google.com/books?id=QijGXwB3zm8C&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=we%20don%27t%20accomplish%20anything%20in%20this%20world%20alone&source=bl&ots=_x-m30JH18&sig=t0y95cgd2T7ycbOrKXinJ_04dk4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO0brCstfeAhWKrFMKHTchDnQQ6AEwE3oECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=we%20don't%20accomplish%20anything%20in%20this%20world%20alone&f=false)* has the quote with 'from.'

Comment: Oh, wow, I see how the transcription error occurred in the first place lol. I shall edit it to reflect that.

Comment: What is stated there is itself a quote, not the original. It begins with "She once noted:".

Comment: @Kris What? I can't find an original text with that phrase and it sounds  like an informal remark, so I doubt it can be attributed better.

Comment: Wikiquote is cautious in noting it as "Unsourced" https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Sandra_Day_O%27Connor